# What would be the postal/delivery address for an orbiting vehicle?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, geostationary

It's possible/likely that one day we'll be able to post/mail/deliver stuff to a non-terrestrial vehicle, such as an orbiting vehicle or an extraterrestrialLy landed vehicle, *without* involving the vehicle's governing organisation (eg NASA).

What would be its address?
Who would have jurisdiction over deciding?

Here are some ideas:

```
<Recipient>
<Name of craft>
<Location> (options of LEO, GSO, HEO, Luna, Mars, LMO)
```

Comment: I think this question is probably too broad (unless you restrict to one country) and too speculative, however you might be onto something: http://www.navy.mil/submit/display.asp?story_id=84519

Comment: Although there are two attempts to answer this question, i think we are getting sidetracked from the point that it can't be answered in a factual way. These attempts are in good faith, but are conversational and not really what the site is designed for. So, i felt moved to stem the flow of conversational juices...

Comment: By the way, @called2voyage was using a moderator ploy of making a comment instead of voting to close, as a moderator vote instantly closes, and cuts off the chance for the community to decide, and develop our collective close policy and skills. Many moderators wish we had the option to vote like regular members for this reason.

Comment: Bohemian, you accepted one of the current answers, which people tend to take to mean that you are satisfied and don't seek more information. However, you have edited your question, which seems to show you are interested in it being reopened. To be reopened it would need to be possible to answer it factually. No way of modifying it so that is possible occurs to me with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would probably just be designated by the [satellite catalogue number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_Catalog_Number) contained in that spacecraft’s [two line element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set).  With that number the orbital postal service could look up your spacecraft’s two line element which would tell them exactly what orbit they would need to be in to rendezvous.   For example, the satellite catalogue number of the ISS is 25544 so if I was sending you a letter the address might look like this

Bohemian

International Space Station, Habitation Module

LEO, 25544

Comment: Or maybe "25544, LEO" (more specific first), like "123 Park Ave, New York"

Comment: If you are specifying the catalogue number, why would you need to specify the orbit further? I see little value being added by the "LEO" qualifier, but could see some value in specifying the central body in the orbit. So you might instead make that "Bohemian, International Space Station, Habitation Module, 25544, Earth orbit". The actual spacecraft is then specified by the pair catalogue number + central body designator ("25544, Earth orbit"), the recipient is specified by the name ("Bohemian"), the rest is mainly for readability and possibly ambiguity resolution.

Comment: Adding vague sorting abilities without the necessity to read and lookup the catalogue number? Allows for bulk sorting before more detailed sorting is applied. Just a possible explanation. Also retains some human readability.

Comment: They would be there for the same reason we include the city and state on postal addresses even though that knowledge is included in the zip code.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you just use the mailing address of the controlling entity of the satellite/module. For example, mail to astronauts on ISS should go to one of

```
[Astronaut's name]
NASA Headquarters
300 E. Street SW, Suite 5R30
Washington, DC 20546
U.S.A


[Cosmonaut's name],
Russian Federal Space Agency
42 Schepkina st.
Moscow 107996 
Russia


[Astronaut's name]
ESA Communication Department
ESRIN
Via Galileo Galilei
Casella Postale 64
I-00044 Frascati
Italy
```

That way the mail will reach the right recipient.

Until actual postal service is established to the satellites, any direct mailing addresses of these, bypassing the ground HQ, are a pure speculation.

Comment: Note that I'm thinking parcel delivery via private launch service, not "mail" or official agency launch

Comment: @Bohemian: then it would be up to the creator of the service to develop the postal address system.